# Is it valid to interpret the coefficient on a difference score while controlling for the baseline score?

Tags: regression, panel-data, time-varying-covariate

I would like to see if a change in scores is predictive of a health outcome Y. However, I'd also like to control for the baseline score. Is the following valid?

$$
Y = c+\beta_1(X_{t=1}-X_{t=0})  + \beta_2X_{t=0} + \epsilon
$$

I know that the model can be rewritten as:
$$
Y=c+\beta_1X_{t=1}+(\beta_2-\beta_1)X_{t=0} + \epsilon
$$

Can I still interpret $\beta_1$ as the effect of a 1 unit change in X on Y?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend instead the equivalent model that is in standard form for linear regression:

$$Y = c + \beta_1X_{t=1} + \beta_2X_{t=0} + \epsilon$$

$\beta_1$ then represents the effect of a one-unit change in $X_{t=1}$ controlling for $X_{t=0}$, as desired.